# Admin-on-REST: onNewRequest not working for AutocompleteInput?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, admin-on-rest

I want to have a a custom input component that

1) has an Autocomplete component allowing selection of a "field"-resource

2) after selecting a "field" populates another SelectInput depending on the selected type of the "field".

What I currently have is:

```
    const renderAutoComplete = ({ input, meta, ...rest }) => {
        return (
            <AutoComplete {...rest} />
        )
    }


    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                    <Field
                        component={renderAutoComplete}
                        name={this.props.fieldSource}
                        hintText="Field"
                        dataSource={this.state.fields}
                        dataSourceConfig={{ text: 'title', value: 'id' }}
                        openOnFocus={true}
                        filter={AutoComplete.caseInsensitiveFilter}
                        onNewRequest={(chosen) => this.handleNewRequest(chosen)}
                    />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <Field
                        component={SelectInput}
                        label="Type-dependent"
                        name={this.props.typeSource}
                        choices={this.state.availableChoices}
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

This works great as far as population of the SelectInput goes and if I use this in a create-form I also get the value of the SelectInput send with the request.

Unforatunately though the "field"-value is not being included in the request.

I had the assumption that I needed a "real" AutocompleteInput here. So I did the following:

```
                    <Field
                        component={AutocompleteInput}
                        name={this.props.fieldSource}
                        hintText="Feld"
                        choices={this.state.fields}
                        dataSourceConfig={{ text: 'title', value: 'id' }}
                        optionText="title"
                        optionValue="id"
                        filter={AutoComplete.caseInsensitiveFilter}
                        onNewRequest={(chosen) => this.handleNewRequest(chosen)}
                    />
```

With this I have the "field"-values being sent in the request but the `onNewRequest`-callback is never executed. Therefore the other SelectInput doesn't receive any values I could sent.

I looked into the node_modules folder where the AutocompleteInput files ares and according to them it should be possible to use this callback here.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong here?

---

Edit in regards to wesley6j comment:

```
<Field
    name="field"
    component={AutocompleteInput}
    choices={choices}
    optionText="title"
    optionValue="id"
    filter={AutoComplete.caseInsensitiveFilter}
    options={{
        onNewRequest: (chosen, index) => console.log(chosen)
    }}
/>
```

...this logs to console but again my values are not set in the request. Can you maybe point me to the right part of the documentation or source code that clears things up on what I would have to do here?

Comment: Are you sure the onNewRequest returns the value in the function argument? Material UI components return events

Comment: Hi @kunalpareek, what value are you referring to? Currently the `handleNewRequest`-function only sets `this.state.availableChoices` so the second field receives the right choices.

Comment: When you use `AutocompleteInput` as field component, you should put `onNewRequest` prop within `options` prop.

Comment: Because `AutocompleteInput` does not accept `onNewRequest` directly, but you can use `options` to override the builtin `onNewRequest` props.

Comment: Hi @wesley6j. I don't quite understand. The documentation of admin-on-rest says about Field-components: `All Field props except name and component are passed to the child component/element.` ....and I also looked into the AutocompleteInput.js in my node_modules and this one seems to take in an `onNewRequest` property as well? Anyway, I tried what you said and used the options-property (will edit original post). This caused the callback to execute but now - again - the value will not be sent in the request?!

Comment: You are right. Having `onNewRequest` inside `options` does not solve all problems. Redux form state can not be updated because you lost this part of code when you replace `onNewRequest`: `input.onChange(choices[index][optionValue]);`

Comment: So there is no way at all to use the `onNewRequest` for some custom stuff without losing the possibility to set the value here?